# postgresql jsonb processing with c api

Tags: postgresql, c-api, jsonb

## Postgres extension development

I am working with C API for **postgres-9.4** installed from ubuntu trusty main repo. This might be a silly question, but please bear with me.

I would like to use a function that converts a `cstring` to `Jsonb*` structure defined in

http://doxygen.postgresql.org/jsonb_8h.html

There are functions doing exactly this already defined in

http://doxygen.postgresql.org/jsonb_8c.html

Namely, the function 
`Datum jsonb_in ( PG_FUNCTION_ARGS )`, however I am not sure if I can call 
this function from C API in a portable and safe manner. As it seems it is intended for being called by postgres from first glance.

I could also use the function `jsonb_from_cstring`

http://doxygen.postgresql.org/jsonb_8c.html#ab23eca28d5880f86a0943d71c90d6654

but it is declared and defined in `jsonb.c` and not declared in json.h, and hence linking with this function is not a very clean solution. I tried finding the symbols for `jsonb_from_cstring` in libpq.so, however there are none. I am guessing I need a non-standard build of postgres?

So the question is, what is the best way to convert a `cstring` to a `Jsonb*` structure from within C API?

## Edit:

The extension gets json data as a string from external source and is supposed to be able to store this string in a `Jsonb` type

Comment: Are you developing a Postgres extension? Or user-defined function to run on server? These functions are not from public interface and you're not supposed to use them otherwise.

Comment: @Tometzky I am developing a postgres extension

Answer (score 3):

This was answered in postgres mailing list

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRCeGL7q_EGTz2=FyQZ2Qrtn1x_76mz3fuR=b7beEug7Wg@mail.gmail.com

Quote:
you can call "input function" - jsonb_in

`Jsonb *targetjsonbvar = DatumGetJsonb(DirectFunctionCall1(jsonb_in,
CStringGetDatum(cstrvalue)));`

Comment: In PG 16.1, it is
`Jsonb *jsonb =
            DatumGetJsonbP(DirectFunctionCall1(jsonb_in, CStringGetDatum(cstrvalue)));`
Note the `P` in `DatumGetJsonbP`